# How to Auto Scale Microservices in Local server without cloud using JAVA

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Hi I am new to the microservices. I have created spring boot(maven) microservices (2 services, 1 gateway and service registry). How can I scale (auto scaling) 2 services without cloud technology. Is it possible in the local configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) and this gives me a cloud-like environment where I can upscale or downscale a service very easily.

You can read here about using [Docker with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/). There is also [this article](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/building-a-microservice-architecture-with-spring-boot-and-docker-part-i).

P.S. Docker and Docker swarm are free or charge (the community editions).

Comment: Can we create another instance of same service ? say, service 2 going to down status at that time, will it create another instance automatically? I need answer for this question exactly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rajasekar If a service goes down then docker will start another instance.