# Autoscaling of Spring cloud OSS microservices

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have developed several micro services using spring cloud Netflix stack (Eureka, Zuul, Zipkin, config server etc.) Is there any open source / free solution available to spin up/down microservices instances. e.g. if CPU usage > 90% for 3 consecutive checking it will add one more instance.

Comment: Autoscalaing is a function of the platform you are running on: Cloud Foundry, Kubernetes or the like. Spring Cloud doesn't know how to deploy new instances.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will try to implement something by my self :)

Comment: Please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058457/how-to-auto-scale-microservices-in-local-server-without-cloud-using-java